# JAVA convert string CSV file into double[] array

Tags: java, arrays, csv, double

I have an issue with the CSV file: here is a sample of the file.

```
4.98    24
9.14    21.6
4.03    34.7
2.94    33.4
5.33    36.2
5.21    28.7
12.43   22.9
19.15   27.1
29.93   16.5
17.1    18.9
20.45   15
13.27   18.9
15.71   21.7
8.26    20.4
10.26   18.2
8.47    19.9
6.58    23.1
14.67   17.5
11.69   20.2
11.28   18.2
```

The aim is to convert it in something like that:

```
double[] column1= {4.98, 9.14, 4.03, 2.94, 5.33, 5.21, 12.43, 19.15}; //but with all the values, here it's just a sample
double [] column2 = {24, 21.6, 34.7, 33.4, 36.2, 28.7, 22.9, 27.1};
```

I don't want to write all the data, I need to do a loop but I don't know how I can do it.

I manage to read the csv file and to split the data but not to convert the result into a double[] array. Here is how I read the file:

```
String fileName = "dataset.csv";
File file = new File(fileName);
String[] values;
try{
    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
    while (inputStream.hasNext()){
        String data = inputStream.next();
        values = data.split(",");
    }
    inputStream.close();

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: create two array lists of doubles, `column1`, `column2`, add `values[0]` to `column1` and `values[1]` to `column2`, after reading all entries, convert lists to arrays using `column1values = column1.toArray( new Double[]{} )`

Comment: **values = data.split(",");** be careful with that, because even your csv(since you say so) file shows that there is no such character as ','(comma) in the whole file

Comment: It's a CSV file, we can't see the comma because I opened it with Excel but there are commas

Comment: @svasa thank you for your answer, I'm going to try :)
ShayHaned thanks for your advice, I will be careful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full working example for Java 7:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try
        {
            String fileName = "dataset.csv";
            File file = new File(fileName);

            // we don't know the amount of data ahead of time so we use lists
            List<Double> col1 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Double> col2 = new ArrayList<>();

            inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            while (inputStream.hasNext())
            {
                String data = inputStream.next();
                String [] arr = data.split(",");

                col1.add(Double.parseDouble(arr[0]));
                col2.add(Double.parseDouble(arr[1]));
            }

            // Covert the lists to double arrays
            double[] column1 = new double[col1.size()];
            double[] column2 = new double[col2.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < col1.size(); i++)
            {
                column1[i] = col1.get(i);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < col2.size(); i++)
            {
                column2[i] = col2.get(i);
            }

            // print out just for verification
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(column1));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(column2));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (inputStream != null)
            {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stream the lines from the file and split them to get a `String[]`, as you did. You can then stream each such array and convert each item to a `double`, and then collect them back to arrays:

```
double[][] data =
    Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
         .map(s -> s.split(","))
         .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray())
         .toArray(double[][]::new);
```

Comment: `s` seems like a bad choice for the name of the array variable here.

Comment: It seems to be a good idea ! Can you tell me which imports I need to do ? I tried:
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
but it is not working

Comment: @anna756825 Can you elaborate on "not working"? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well I have errors: "data", "Files" and "Paths" are highlighted just as if the import are not the good ones

Comment: @anna756825 That doesn't answer his question. Can you tells us what the error is and not the symptom in your IDE. That doesn't help us to help you.

Comment: @anna756825 It's really hard to answer with so little data. Can you share the exact code and error you're getting?

Comment: I manage to solve the problem ! But I agree with @MichaelMarkidis there is a problem with 's'

Comment: I have juste realized it's Java8, do you know how I can do with Java7 ?